# Initialize an array in Go dynamically

Tags: arrays, go

Can anyone help me on how to initialize an array in Go dynamically? Given is a list of items of a directory:

```golang
    entries, err := d.ReadDir(-1)
    count := int64(len(entries))
    array = [count]string{} // invalid array length count
```

Assuming the goal is to write a function called:

`func getFileNamesOfDirectory(path string) []string`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: No, you can't. Array will be evaluated when the program compiling.

Comment: Gotcha. In this case, how would I create a list of file names and return this as an array? `funcgetFileList(path string) []string`

Comment: You can use slice. https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/7

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my question with a more practical approach.

Comment: Use a slice as suggested by spike014. 
 Here's the code: `result := make([]string, len(entries); for i, e := range entries { result[i] = e.Name() }`. Take the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/list).

Comment: That looks fantastic Cerise. Does this mean spikes answer is incorrect? The `make` function looks like it is what I am looking for.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Feel free to post this as an answer. Happy to accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. **Array will be evaluated when the program compiling.**

You can code like:

```golang
entries, err := d.ReadDir(-1)
count := len(entries)
array = make([]string, count)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? You begin with that a dynamic array isn't possible, but then this looks like a dynamically created array. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: In Go, array is different from slice. When writing a go program, for most common use-cases, you’ll be using slice instead of array. An array is fixed in size. But slices can be dynamic. The number of elements in a slice can grow dynamically. But, keep in mind that slice uses array in the backend. Slice by itself doesn’t store any data. Think of slice like a reference to an array. @HelloWorld